# How to deliver and save the query result from an existing table into another new table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am using entityframework codefirst for a new database and an existing database. Now I want to save the query result from table Products in Northwind to a new one named NewProducts which is in the NewProductContext. 
In this solution I created a class named NewProductContext, which I just used for creating an new database with two columns id and newname;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new NorthwindContext())
        {
            {

                Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Product: ");
                var productname = Console.ReadLine();

                var product = new Product { ProductName = productname };
                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //LINQ query for the table
                var query = from p in db.Products
                            //where p.ProductName.Contains("A")
                            orderby p.ProductName.Length
                            select p;

                Console.WriteLine("All products in the database:");
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ProductName);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    /*    using (var db1 = new NewProductContext())
        {
            foreach (var item in query) 
            {   
                var newpro = item;
                db.NewProducts.Add(item)
                db.Savechanges();
            }
        }*/
```

The method in comments is just my thinking, I know that there are many errors. But can anybody provide a new method to save the query result?
I created the database by this code

```
namespace CodeFirstExistingDatabaseSample
{
    public class NewProduct
    {
        public int NewProductID { get; set; }
        public string NewProductName { get; set; }

    }

    public class NewProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<NewProduct> NewProducts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have two tables both which EF has created for you and you want to copy the contents of one into the other? Am I right?

Comment: For as far as I know you must copy them one by one as in your code. Bulk insert is not possible.

Comment: Your NewProductContext() what class is it mapped to? For example, usually in the context you have properties of DbSet<T>.

Comment: @Onam hi,one table was just from northwind, I used ef for existing database to create the model, just the new one was created by myself. _namespace CodeFirstExistingDatabaseSample { public class NewProduct { public int NewProductID { get; set; } public string NewProductName { get; set; } } public class NewProductContext : DbContext { public DbSet<NewProduct> NewProducts { get; set; } } } _This is the code I created for the new table I wanna map to.

Comment: @Onam I edited the code at the original question, hope I can help you to understand my problem and help me later :)

Comment: @RonDeijkers U mean I can not use the SqlBulkCopy method? WHat do u mean one by one in my code?

Comment: Just do a select into sql statement, or put one inside a stored proc and call it. Pulling all the data into your client to push it back up is inefficient.

Comment: What I mean is that the code that is commented out is what I think the only option if you want to do it through EF. 
I also agree with Tony btw.

Comment: Do `var query = (...).ToList()` to begin with. Then you can copy the products to `NewProduct` objects one by one.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Sorry I am not farmiliar with the stored procedure, could u made an example about your suggestion?

Comment: @GertArnold, thank you Gert, but could u pls explain a little bit more in Details, Where should I add this query to ?

Comment: A stored procedure is some sql with a name and arguments that sits in the database along with the tables and stuff. Quick google and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

How about plain sql ?
something like that

```
INSERT INTO targetDatabase.new_products (id,newname) 
(SELECT id, name FROM sourceDatabase.products);
```

Of course the two databases must be on the same server